# On Android, is ”Observable.interval(RxJava)“ affected by power saving policies?

Tags: android, rx-java, foreground-service

Does it continue to run after the screen is turned off?

I have added the app to the battery-optimized whitelist, and created ForegroundService.

Comment: You should additionally acquire PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK. The foreground service itself is not enough if the code should execute on turned off screen. However the battery consumption will be significant.